# Objective C Post Request

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I have written a Php code using post Method and currently placed on server, When i make request to server the response is null.

The code is as follow's:

```
/json responce array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if(isset($_POST['device_id']) && isset($_POST['country'])){

    $device = $_POST['device_id'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];

    $sql = "SELECT country_id FROM newsletter_country WHERE country_name = '$country';";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) or die(mysql_error());
    $c_id = $row['country_id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE device = '$device';";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){

        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $device;
    }
    else{

        $qry = "INSERT INTO users(country_id,country,device,user_status) VALUES($c_id,'$country','$device','NEW');";
        $res = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
        if($res){
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["user"]["country"] = $country;
        $response["user"]["device_id"]=$device;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User Successfully Registered with ".$device;
        }
        else{
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_message"] = "Unknow Error occur try again later";
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}else{

        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unable to Register. Parameters are not complete";
        echo json_encode($response);
```

The same code work's perfectly for android, Please have a review to Objective C code:

```
NSString *device_id = @"test@gmail.com";
NSString *country = @"Mexico";

NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/linkhere/adduser.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"device_id=%@&country=%@",device_id,country];
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];


 if (responseData != nil){
    NSMutableArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:&err];

    NSLog(@"%@",json);

}
```

Thanks for reviewing and helping.

Comment: can you NSLog the err to see if everything is fine, also change `options:0` to `options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`

Comment: @Talha if you are new in iOS development, why you don't start with the SWIFT language?
Any how, Welcome to SO. Please review before asking a question.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @maetsoh I tried changing the options to NSJSONReadingMutableContainers but still receiving null.

Comment: @Ali Can you please verify if there is any issue in my code? i will be thankful to you

Comment: I posted that you're using a deprecated method, which, if you really want to know any 'issues' that would be one. It's going to break your code eventually. And, you're not really giving us any sort of error response. What do you mean "null?" Put that in a comment. Help us help you.

Comment: @BrooksHanes When i remove [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; from my code i receive error from server:

{
    error = 1;
    "error_msg" = "Unable to Register. Parameters are not complete";
}

The issue is in passing the variable to server...

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSURLSession as NSURLConnection is deprecated. That's step one.